# Error in React mapping when JSON.parse on local storage fails

Tags: json, reactjs, parsing, mapping, local-storage

I have a react app that uses local storage to maintain its state with cookies, but when a cookie exists that has a bad value, the code errors causing the whole app to break. I'm not sure exactly what cookie is the problem, but certain cookies seem to cause `JSON.parse(localStorage[key]) to fail.

```
const getLocalStorage = () => {
    const storage = R.compose(
        R.fromPairs,
        R.map(([key]) => [key, JSON.parse(localStorage[key])]),
        R.toPairs, // [[key, value], [key, value]]
    )(localStorage);

    return storage;
};
```

I'd like to just add some error handling so that cookies that cannot be parsed are ignored, but I'm not sure how to do that in this syntax. How can I fix the code so that if `JSON.parse` fails, it doesn't break?

Answer (score 0):

So you have two options here, the first one is the filter out any cookies that would return an error on parsing before you do your map like so:

```
const getLocalStorage = () => {
    const storage = R.compose(
        R.fromPairs,
        R.filter([key] => {
            try{
                JSON.parse(localStorage[key]);
                return true;
            }
            catch(error){
                console.log(error);
                return false;           
            }
        }).map(([key]) => [key, JSON.parse(localStorage[key])]),
        R.toPairs, // [[key, value], [key, value]]
    )(localStorage);

    return storage;
};
```

Or you could try using an Array.reduce() like this:

```
const getLocalStorage = () => {
    const storage = R.compose(
        R.fromPairs,
        R.reduce((acc, curr) => 
        {
            try{
                acc.push[[key, JSON.parse(localStorage[key])]];
            }
            catch(error){
                console.log(error);         
            }
            return acc;
        }),
        R.toPairs, // [[key, value], [key, value]]
    )(localStorage);

    return storage;
};
```